# Margin auto is not centering

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering why margin auto isn't working? my parent div margin auto works but my inner margin auto is not in center.

```css
.rankings_page{
    width: 750px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin: auto;
    height: 800px;
}
.tab-group {
    margin: auto;
}
.toggle_btn{

    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div className="rankings_page">
    <div className="tabgroup">
        <div className="toggle_btn">
            Country
        </div>
        <div className="toggle_btn">
            City
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: By "not centering" I suppose you mean "not centering vertically"? You can't use `margin: auto` to center an element vertically: use flexbox instead.

Comment: div will have full width by default so there is nothing to center

Answer (score 1):

The `margin: auto` trick only works if you want to **horizontally center** your elements. It will not work to vertically center your elements, because of how CSS deals with vertical margins differently.

You should use CSS flexbox instead: it is specifically made to allow layouts like this possible:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Also, you need to update the `tabgroup` selector, because there is no `-` in the class in your markup. See proof-of-concept example:

```css
.rankings_page {
  width: 750px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 800px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabgroup {
  display: flex;
}

.toggle_btn {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="rankings_page">
  <div class="tabgroup">
    <div class="toggle_btn">
      Country
    </div>
    <div class="toggle_btn">
      City
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```